# Magento REST API: Invalid webservice adapter specified

Tags: magento-1.9

I just started Magento integration.

I looked at some related questions around the cloud with regards to my concern but I don't find any fitted answer since Im using IIS 7.5.

My current config is:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.php" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>      
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Rewrite to api.php" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^api/rest(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?type=rest/{R:1}" />
            </rule>             
            <rule name="REMOVE INDEX.PHP" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/index.php/(.+)$" negate="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" />
            </rule>             
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Do you have any idea/answer why I'm getting "**Invalid webservice adapter specified.**" every time I visit "http://magentohost/api/rest/customers" on my browser?

Comment: this one works for me http://magentohost/api/api/V2_soap?wsdl=1
but the REST API doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There only seems to have a wrong rewrite rule in my configuration with regards to api.php.

The "Invalid webservice adapter specified" error is now gone and now it says 403 - forbidden: access denied which is I expected.

I'll give it a try now using my http client tool.

[Btw, found the answer here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/REST-API-issue-can-not-read-api-data-in-IIS-7-5-who-could-tell/td-p/12992)

Answer (score 0):

This error originates from: Mage_Api_Model_Server::initialize

Check your .htaccess file and un comment following code

```
############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

After this restart your server.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm using IIS and I also made same rewrite rule as per your comment in my config. Was there a
 <Directory /var/www/magento>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
equivalent in IIS so that I could try it?
It seems a directory issue because I have a log error which says "failed to open stream: No such file or directory".

Comment: Oh do you mean should I make a rewrite rule for this "RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]" for that as well?